# Delete a cookie from a seperate sub-page

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

Sorry if this question is a duplicate, but the examples found in the other questions do not work for me.  Lets say I store a cookie "name" on domain.com/page/page/page, with the domain set to .domain.com, and path=/.  I am trying to delete the cookie from domain.com/page/page/otherpage, but it won't delete.  Any tips?  I have tried using document.cookie in the past and setcookie() in php, but nothing will work :(.
My javascript attempts:

```
document.cookie = "name=;expires=Thu, 21 Sep 1979 00:00:01 UTC;";
```

PHP attempts (top of page, before any output):

```
setcookie("name", "", time()-3600);"
```

**UPDATE**
I am using document.cookie, with domain as .domain.com, and path=/, and the cookies are accessible all throughout *.domain.com.  I am checking the cookies still exist in document.cookie, throught firefox/chrome's dev console.

Comment: Cookie code and recipe = Better kitchen help. Plus, what's the relation to JS?

Comment: @Fred-ii- i was using document.cookie, will add code in a sec.

Comment: How did you set the cookie? Are you sure the domain is set properly? How do you check if the cookie is deleted?

Comment: @JonasB I use document.cookie and a cookie manager to check the are set.  I use document.cookie to set it.

Comment: Can you provide the full document.cookie code to set the cookie?

Comment: @JonasB oops, document.cookie="name=true; domain=.domain.com; path=/"